# Android 4.4 Kitkat custom view actionbar not filling the whole width

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to have a Simple actionbar with a custom view, but I get the following result:

For demonstration I created a simple xml with a yellow background color which is supposed to take the whole width.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/yellow"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/action_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/action_save"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="@string/save" />

    <ImageView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_actionbar_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I use the following theme for my Application:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
```

[image: actionbar]

This is the actionbar initialization code:

```
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The solution is adding :

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

The code should look something like:

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);//set the custom view
```

Comment: @NemesisDoom worked for me, add it right after `getSupportActionBar()` call.

Comment: @chhameed have you called that method right after getSupportActionBar(); call?

Comment: yes exactly, i called it right after  getSupportActionBar() call. but it does nothing ....

Comment: write the following code:
 actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
 actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: @JerryGu Since this post is for Android 4.4, I asked a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298282/android-actionbars-custom-view-not-filling-parent)

Comment: i still have problem on android 5

Answer (score 5):

@NemesisDoom: Please make sure that you use ActionBar from the support.v7 library rather that one from the Android API (this second one will not work certainly). If still doesn't work, add the further changes:

styles.xml (your action bar style section):

```
 <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/_pixel</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/_pixel</item>
```

_pixel is 1x1.png image, transparent.

your activity:

```
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```