# Android ActionBar's custom view not filling parent

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-5.0-lollipop, android-actionbar-compat

Similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172256/android-4-4-kitkat-custom-view-actionbar-not-filling-the-whole-width), but has some key differences. Most notably being that the accepted answer *did* work until the latest support library releases.

Here's the custom view layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#FFDD0000">

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, when you try to set just the custom view:

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
  actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
  actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

You end up with a custom layout that doesn't fill the entire width:
[image]

To make this more interested, I have a similar setup in a different app:

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
  actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
  actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
  actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
```

This *did* work, until I updated the support libraries to v21. Once I did, I ended up with the same issue on apps that previously haven't had that issue.

So, my question is, is there a way to make a custom view actionbar fill the width using the latest support library?

***Edit*** After doing some more tests, I found that compiling with targetSdkVersion/compileSdkVersion set to 19 and having v7:19.0.1 (or v7:19.1.0) for the library doesn't have this issue (has the home icon, which is taken care of with the later code), confirming that this is definitely an issue with the latest release.

Comment: See answer on a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/a/26454325/624109

Answer (score 32):

1

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar_title_back,
            null);
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
actionBar.setCustomView(view, layoutParams);
Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) view.getParent();
parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
```

2  Use Toolbar

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("");
mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
mTitle.setText(title);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>       
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:popupBackground="@color/red"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupTheme"
        app:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Toolbar Title"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="17.0sp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you explain how this specifically addresses the issue with the latest release the OP asked about?

Comment: @tuder but i m getting NPE when i m trying to launch my app first time  and errro is on this line  parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0); this shows that parent is null

Comment: @Erum   check your layout's   id   or   your Actionbar's  version, i use android.support.v7.appcompat

Comment: @tuder, Thanks a lot. it works..

Comment: Thank you. Tried option 1, which worked. Note: here are the import statements I had to add: import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar; import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams; import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Answer (score 7):

use
Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) customNav.getParent();
        parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
it will work

Answer (score 6):

add like this in your onCreate method

```
 ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar();
        action.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

 Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar)action.getCustomView().getParent();
        toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);
        toolbar.getContentInsetEnd();
        toolbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

In your XML code add these attributes:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/re_app_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">
```

it will fit all width of the view.